# Load WebAssembly module only once / Singleton

Tags: javascript, import, singleton, webassembly

I want to use WebAssembly modules in my React app. The modules are loaded when the app starts. Now I want to reuse this wasm module in another Javascript module.

How can I reuse these wasm modules in other JS modules? Do I really have to load the modules again?

Loading wasm in the main module:

```
Promise.all([
    import("webassembly-tests-rust")
    //...
])
    .then(modules => {
        // how to store the module to make it available in other modules?
        wasm["rust"] = modules[0];
        //...
    })
```

Other module:

```
wasm.rust.somefunction();
```

Comment: Why don't you make the wasm module an ES6 module, then expect it tree-shaken?

Comment: You mean static `import wasm from "module";`? This is not supported for WebAssembly modules. You have to load them async (dynamic import or fetch()).
My current solution is to save the loaded modules under `window.wasm` but I assume there is a better way.

Answer (score 0):

Would it work like this?

**wasm.js**

```
let wasm
export const getWasm = () =>
  wasm
    ? Promise.resolve(wasm)
    : import('webassembly-tests-rust').then(_wasm => {
        wasm = _wasm;
        return wasm;
      })
```

**module.js**

```
import getWasm from 'wasm.js'
Promise.all([
    getWasm
    //...
])
    .then(modules => {
        modules[0].someFunction = () => console.log('foo')
        //...
    })
```

**Other module:**

```
import getWasm from 'wasm.js'
getWasm().then(wasm => wasm.somefunction()) // console.log('foo')
```